# Google Map Marker from Two List

Tags: flutter, google-maps, google-maps-markers

I have two list in my project but in this particular page i will need to retrieve the data from two `list` to display all the marker i have. I am using Firestore to save the `LatLng` and other info. The reason why i use two `list` is that both of the data are from different collection. Or is there any other method to store all of the data from both collection to just 1 `list`?

[image: locations]

[image: markers]

```
Map<MarkerId, Marker>busmarkers = <MarkerId, Marker>{};

    void initMarker(specify, specifyId) async{
      var markerIdVal = specifyId;
      final MarkerId markerId = MarkerId(markerIdVal);
      final Marker marker = Marker(
          markerId: markerId,
          icon: BitmapDescriptor.fromAsset("assets/images/markerIconBus.png"),
          position: LatLng(specify['location'].latitude, specify['location'].longitude),
          onTap: openInfo,
      );
      setState(() {
        busmarkers[markerId] = marker;
      });
    }

    Future <void> getMarker() async{
      Firestore.instance.collection('markers').snapshots().listen((myData) {
        if(myData.documents.isNotEmpty){
          for (int i = 0; i < myData.documents.length; i++){
            initMarker(myData.documents[i].data, myData.documents[i].documentID);
          }
        }
      });
      setState(() {
      });
    }
```

This is the first list where i will get the `LatLng` from the `marker` collection.

```
Firestore.instance
            .collection('locations')
            .snapshots()
            .listen((driverLocation){
          driverLocation.documents.forEach((dLocation){
            latitudeD = dLocation.data['latitude'];
            longitudeD = dLocation.data['longitude'];

            busStop.add(
                Marker(
                  markerId: MarkerId('driverLocation'),
                  draggable: false,
                  icon: BitmapDescriptor.fromAsset("assets/images/bus.png"),
                  onTap: () {
                  },
                  position: LatLng(latitudeD, longitudeD),
                ));
          });
          setState(() {
          });
        });
```

This is the second list where i will store latitude and longitude into a `busStop` list.

Any documentation or sample of code is much appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: please share some code, and images of your Firestore data structure, in order to get better advise and feedback.

Comment: sorry ya for that. Already updated my question. Thank you.

Comment: What is inside location and markers?

Comment: really sorry ya updated my question once again. Thank you.

Comment: Since you are storing LatLng data in your markers document, wouldn't that work? If you are able to store them there, there is no need for a separate document holding only LatLng. What do you think?

Comment: actually its different for both of them. In my case the locations is the location of the driver while the marker is the marker of the bus stop and i wanted to show all of the LatLng in a GoogleMap marker

Comment: or do you mean like i insert both of the data into the same collection? but if this is really the case how can i get specific information like driver and the marker how can i differentiate both of them? is it by using `where` when i am listening to changes? or is there other method? sorry if i cause any misunderstanding.

Comment: i found our a solution. By adding them both into this `Map<MarkerId, Marker>markers = <MarkerId, Marker>{};` and read it from the `Marker` of `GoogleMap` all of my marker got out. Thank you.